# if condition is true or skip all else conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

**xyz.html**

```
<p id = x ngClick = close($event)></p>
<p id = y ngClick = close($event)></p>
<p id = z ngClick = close($event)></p>
<h1 id = a ngClick = close()></h1>
```

**xyz.js**

```
function close(event)
if (event.target.id === x){
....
}else if(event.target.id === y){
....
}else if(event.target.id === z){
.....
}
```

This function is to close current window and check for the event but when I'm not passing this event in other **close** methods(h1 tag) I'm getting the event is undefined error.

Comment: `if (!event) { /* handle here */ } else if (event.target.id == x)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function close(event){
     if(event===undefined){

     //H1 got clicked
       return;
     }

     if (event.target.id === x){
     ....
     }else if(event.target.id === y){
     ....
     }else if(event.target.id === z){
     .....
     }
   }
```

Comment: Better write `if (typeof(event) == "undefined") {...}`

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct. You need first check if event is defined, because you can't directly access target property if event is undefined.

```
function close(event)
   if(event){
    if (event.target.id === x){
    ....
    }else if(event.target.id === y){
    ....
    }else if(event.target.id === z){
    .....
    }
    }else{
           //H1 click condition
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.close = function(event) {
  if (!event) return;

  switch (event.target.id) {
    case "x":
      ...
      break;
    case "y":
      ...
      break;
    case "z":
      ...
      break;
    default:
      ...
      break;
  }
}
```